# special case of merge in R

Tags: r, merge

I'm trying to solve this:

For example:

**Warehouse**

```
       id amount size
1 cymbals      5   24
2  snares      3   10
3    tom1      2   19
```

**Incoming**

```
      id amount size
1 snares      2   15
```

**Resulting**

```
       id amount size
1 cymbals      5   24
2  snares      5   15
3    tom1      2   19
```

I am newby in R, so I was looking for the most elegant/legible way of getting the 'resulting' (I am not concerned with performance). Resulting would be:  taking every incoming item, loop in the warehouse if it exists: add the amounts, and replace the size with the new size; if it doesn't exist, add it.

Comment: I have checked this merge https://www.statmethods.net/management/merging.html but I am not getting the desired result...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `dplyr`, we can bind the two dataframes together , group them by `id` and calculate the `sum` of `amount` and take the `last` value of `size` so if the value is present in `incoming` it will take it from there or else it will take the `size` value from `warehouse` dataframe.

```
library(dplyr)
bind_rows(warehouse, incoming) %>%
          group_by(id) %>%
          summarise(amount = sum(amount), 
                    size = last(size))


#   id      amount  size
#  <chr>    <int> <int>
#1 cymbals      5    24
#2 snares       5    15
#3 tom1         2    19
```

Comment: thanks! works like a charm, but I do not understand the code, what is "%>%". Also I get several warnings, how can I avoid them?

Comment: @Chicago1988 `"%>%"`  is known as pipe operator. It is used for data chaining in `dplyr`.  The warnings may be because the column `id` must be a `factor`,  change it to character and it should be fine.